# Gparted funkiness - won't recognize 1TB, full-hdd /home partition, but recognizes ext4 and /home label

Tags: partitioning, gparted, disk-utility

I have a 1TB SATA hard disk from my old desktop, and the entire thing is an ext4 /home partition (/, /boot, and swap were all on another hdd).  It is now in a USB2 enclosure and I want to use it to back up my current laptop /home.

To do this I need to shrink the /home partition on the 1TB backup drive.  It only uses about 500GB so that shouldn't be a problem, I'll start the laptop with an Ubuntu live USB, plug in the 1TB drive, and use Gparted to shrink the 1TB /home partition to ~500GB.

Then I can create a second partition in the newly freed space, and `cp -ax` my laptop's /home over to it.

Unfortuntely, Ubuntu Live USB can detect and mount the external hdd, and Gparted can see it's there, but [Gparted can't read it](https://i.imgur.com/dv1xS.png) and hence can't resize it.  [Disk Utility reports the drive is fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzH2Y.png), no errors, so I'm not sure what's the problem.  See linked pics, worth a thousand words.

Anyone know what the problem is here?  Any pointers in the right direction much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The disk is fine, but the partition's filesystem isn't.

Close gparted, and run this to check (and fix) the partition:

```
sudo fsck /dev/sdd1
```

After it fixes the errors, gparted will be able to resize it.

The is equivalent of using Disk Utilitiy's "Check Filesystem" button. I still prefer the command-line version to see all the messages and errors that may be, but I'm a control freak. If you're not, go ahead and use the GUI button, I agree it's much simpler :)

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I ran it and the only error it found was missing lost+found, and recreated it.  Still same problem wth Gparted though, nothing changed.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you mount and browse the files there?

Comment: Yes, the live USB automounts it as /media/home and I have no trouble browsing the files there, reading docs or playing music directly off /media/home works fine.  Baffling why Gparted is getting confused about it.

Comment: Puzzling indeed. Unmount it before starting gparted (may use the "Eject" button in nautilus), and then please provide a new screenshot for me